# Output filter for default TV value?

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

In 2.3.2, the ne=`` and notempty output filters don't register default TV content in resources. So if you have a resource with a default TV value, the output filters will skip over it.

Does anyone know a way to display default TV values with output filters?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this question has been answered, at least in part, here:
[MODX Forums](http://forums.modx.com/thread/97297/output-filter-for-default-tv-value)

If properly constructed, the notempty output filter should work as expected with default TV values.